# error while implementing email verification in meteor app

Tags: meteor, email-validation

I received the following error while implementing [https://github.com/ideaq/meteor-email](http://email%20in%20meteor)

Modifications were made in the following file:

In your server/server.js file add the following MAIL_URL config line:

process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://xxxxx%40gmail.com:yyyyy@smtp.gmail.com:465/";

Where xxxxx is your gmail username and yyyyy is your gmail password.
Send Your First Email Through Gmail

In your server/server.js file add this email directive

Email.send({
  from: "meteor.email.2014@gmail.com",
  to: "your-personal-email-here@gmail.com",
  subject: "Meteor Can Send Emails via Gmail",
  text: "Its pretty easy to send emails via gmail."
});

As per the link

> W20150312-14:09:25.220(5.5)? (STDERR)
>   W20150312-14:09:25.222(5.5)? (STDERR) AuthError: Invalid login - 534-5.7.14

Comment: I received email from gmail that sign-in attempt was blocked. How to proceed?

Comment: did you got any solutions ?am also stuck with it